# Making Eclipse follow the PEP 8 formatting standards?

Tags: python, eclipse, pep8

Is there any way to make Eclipse follow [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) code formatting standards by default, and show warnings if such standards are broken?

Comment: Tune the Eclipse's editor settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ulidtko said in his comment, you can set the Eclipse Python editor to generate code in a certain way.  If the Eclipse Python Editor has a `Format` option, you can format the Python code based on the Eclipse Python editor settings.

However, you can't force anyone to use the `Format` option.